It seems it's not possible to define which shell to use with variables in Github action?
It seems I can't define with a variable which shell should be used.
I want to reduce code, that's why I want to define which shell I use via a variable.
If I remove the last use in my example, and only make the env for the variables, or the echo they are there. So it's not that the variables are not set. They are set.
I haven't seen anything like this in the documentation yet, but it makes sense that the variable for the bash can't be set.
Original code with the failing Github Action log
Has anyone seen how to make this more dynamic?
jobs:
  regular:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ macos, ubuntu, windows]
      fail-fast: false # Allows to see results from other combinations
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@692973e3d937129bcbf40652eb9f2f61becf3332 # v4.1.7
    ......
      - name: Set OS-specific variables for Windows
        if: matrix.os == 'windows'
        run: |
          echo "OS_PATH=windows" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "OS_FILE_EXTENSION=ps" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "OS_SHELL=pwsh" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        shell: bash

      - name: Set OS-specific variables for macOS and Ubuntu
        if: matrix.os != 'windows'
        run: |
          echo "OS_PATH=linux_mac" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "OS_FILE_EXTENSION=sh" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "OS_SHELL=bash" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        shell: bash

      - name: print out vars
        id: printOutVars
        shell: bash
        run: env
      - name: test echo
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.OS_PATH }}
          echo ${{ env.OS_SHELL }}
          echo ${{ env.OS_FILE_EXTENSION }}
        shell: bash
      - name: Download Issues with end limit
        id: normalIssuesWithEndLimit
        run: ./${{ env.OS_PATH }}/magpi-issue-downloader.${{ env.OS_FILE_EXTENSION }} -l 2
        shell: ${{ env.OS_SHELL }}


I changed it now to use no specific shell, as pwsh is use automatically in windows and bash automatically on mac/linux.
But it's not what I wanted.

It's not supported as indicated in the error: "Invalid workflow file: The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/testing-regular-issues.yml (Line: 64, Col: 16): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.OS_SHELL .github/workflows/testing-regular-issues.yml (Line: 69, Col: 16): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.OS_SHELL". What is your use case? What do you want to achieve with this?

@Azeem - I wanted to be able to set the right shell.
but I found out, it's set anyway automatically. so I can live with it

It seems, it's not possible.
And: it uses anyway automatically the right shell, bash for linux and powershell for windows. so it's enough for me.
